# Python, pickling list to file

Tags: python, list, pickle

I got a problem in my quiz challenge. After the quiz, points and name of player should be sent to dat file. Problem is when i try to open saved file, i see only one name:score record. Where is a mistake?
Whole code: [code](https://pastebin.com/SammCSAX?fbclid=IwAR19PYIvueDLHCpTmM3G2EePZtZxw6iUf9eUp8wGHHKtRTPcKniyXLAdbuI)

In code, add_score def should save score to list, and after whole code i want to open it. Can someone help me?

```
def add_score(name,score):
    """
    Dodaje wynik do osobnego pliku .
    :param name:
    :param score:
    :return:
    """

    my_list = []
    scores = (name,score)
    my_list.append(scores)
    with open("score_games.dat", "ab") as f:
        pickle.dump(my_list, f)
    f.close()
```

Then when i try to open scores:

```
main()
print("Wyniki gry:")
with open("score_games.dat", "rb") as f:
    my_list_1 = pickle.load(f)
    print(my_list_1)


f.close()
```

Comment: What happens? Post the full error message and fix your indentation

Comment: There is no error. For example. If i get 20 points from 2 answers, i enter my name, and it should be pickled in file score_game.dat. It works. But when i trying to open file, and read the list, only one element is showed. For example: i want to show 5 scores, it shows only one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is that each time you call `add_score()` you create a brand new list with a single entry and then pickle that. Thus when you load the pickle file, you get back the last list pickled which contains just one entry.

`add_score()` should first load the pickled list, then add the score to it, and then pickle it.

```
def add_score(name,score):
    """
    Dodaje wynik do osobnego pliku .
    :param name:
    :param score:
    :return:
    """

    try:
        # Load the existing list of scores first, if it exists
        with open("score_games.dat", "rb") as f:
            my_list = pickle.load(f)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        my_list = []

    scores = (name,score)
    my_list.append(scores)
    with open("score_games.dat", "ab") as f:
        pickle.dump(my_list, f)
    f.close()
```

Comment: Thanks, I missed that.